# Gregory's Series gives close, but incorrect value for the results?

Tags: java

THE PROBLEM:

> The number “pi” (3.14159...) can not be expressed as a simple ratio of two numbers. Instead, the value of pi is typically calculated by summing up the terms of an infinite number series. As more and more terms in the series are evaluated, the sum approaches the “true” value of pi. One series that can be used for this purpose is called the Gregory series, which computes the value of pi as follows:
>   pi = 4/1 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9 – 4/11 + …
>
> Observe that the numeric values of the terms of the series get smaller and smaller as the calculation progresses. For example, the value of the 1st term is 4/1 = 4, the 2nd term is 4/3 = 1.333…, the 3rd term is 4/5 = 0.8, and so on.
>
> Write a program that calculates the value of pi using the Gregory series. The input to the program will be a decimal value called limit. The program shall proceed to calculate the value of pi by summing up the terms of the series, but only until such time that the value of the term being summed becomes less than or equal to the value of limit, at which point the program terminates the summation. Thus, the last term of the series that is added to the sum is the first term whose value is less than or equal to the value of limit.
>
> The program then prints out the calculated value of pi at that point, as well as the actual number of terms that were summed up by the calculation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Limit");
        double limit=kb.nextDouble();

        int TermsSum=0;
        double PiVal=0;
        double min=1;
        double PiCon = (4.0 / min);
        while (limit<=PiCon) {
            if (limit <= PiCon) {
                TermsSum++;
                PiVal += (PiCon);
                min += 2;
                PiCon = (4.0 / min);
            }
            if (limit <= PiCon) {
                TermsSum++;
                PiVal += (-(PiCon));
                min += 2;
                PiCon = (4.0 / min);
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Limit: "+limit);
        System.out.println("Pi Value: "+PiVal);
        System.out.println("Terms Summed: "+TermsSum);
    }
}
```

The Expected result if I input the following limits are as follows

```
Limit: 0.075 = Pi: 3.1058897382719475 = Terms Summed: 28
Limit: 0.00001 = Pi: 3.141597653564762 = Terms Summed: 200001
```

My Results in the current program are

```
Limit: 0.075 = Pi: 3.1786170109992202 = Terms Summed: 27
Limit: 0.00001 = Pi: 3.1415876535897618 = Terms Summed: 200000
```

Comment: Why do you feel that your results are off? You should expect your results to be "close but not perfect", close enough for the limits given.

Comment: Floating point math...

Comment: It didn't match the desired output unfortunately

Comment: Re "it didn't match the desired output..." -- According to whom? Based on what criteria?

Comment: As an experiment, replace `double` with `BigDecimal` - does it match now?

Comment: BigDecimal didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I am not getting the logic that you developped: You go into a loop `while (limit <= PiCon)` and the first statement inside the loop is `if (limit <= PiCon)`. This is a check that _must_ always be `true`. Additionally, you have the same `if` statement two times. For me, it seems that you can simplify the whole loop.

Comment: I am having troubles with and how to utilize the loop given that there are 2 equations in it. Also I removed the other if loop

Comment: *BigDecimal didn't work unfortunately* What do you mean by that? Sure, you would have to rewrite your code, and performance would be impacted, but for sure: any algorithm or computation you can express with `double` variables can of course be written to use BigDecimal objects instead.

Comment: What @GhostCat said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation in number of iteration were wrong. I have corrected your code. Also I have printed the series for convenience. Now the value is as expected.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Limit");
            double limit=kb.nextDouble();

            int TermsSum=1;
            double min=1;
            double PiVal= 4.0 / min;
            double PiCon = 4.0 / min;
            System.out.print("4.0 /" + min);
            while (limit<=PiCon) {
                if (limit <= PiCon) {
                    TermsSum++;
                    min += 2;
                    PiCon = (4.0 / min);
                    PiVal += (-(PiCon));
                    System.out.print("-"+"4.0 /" + min);
                }
                if (limit <= PiCon) {
                    TermsSum++;
                    min += 2;
                    PiCon = (4.0 / min);
                    PiVal += (PiCon);
                    System.out.print("+"+"4.0 /" + min);
                }


            }
            System.out.println("Limit: "+limit);
            System.out.println("Pi Value: "+PiVal);
            System.out.println("Terms Summed: "+TermsSum);
        }
```